# How do I update multiple records under one "Where" clause? (Oracle SQL)

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I am using *Oracle SQL* and am having trouble updating a large amount of specific records from my `CTRL_NUMBER` *table*. Currently, when I want to only update one record, the following expression works:

```
UPDATE STOCK
SET PCC_AUTO_KEY=36 WHERE CTRL_NUMBER=54252
```

But, since I have *over 1,000 records to update*, I do not want to type this in for each record (`CTRL_NUMBER`). So I attempted the following with only two records, and the database did not update with the new `PCC_AUTO_KEY` in the `SET` condition.

```
UPDATE STOCK
SET PCC_AUTO_KEY=36 WHERE CTRL_NUMBER=54252 AND CTRL_NUMBER=58334
```

When I execute the above expression, I do not receive any error codes and it will let me commit the expression, but the database information does not change after I verify the `CTRL_NUMBER`.

How else could I approach this update effort or how should I change my expression to successfully update the `PCC_AUTO_KEY` for multiple `CTRL_NUMBER`?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: Thank you all for your help! The suggestions for: UPDATE STOCK SET PCC_AUTO_KEY=36 WHERE CTRL_NUMBER IN (54252, 58334) worked exactly how I needed them too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second `Update` command, you have:

```
WHERE CTRL_NUMBER=54252 AND CTRL_NUMBER=58334
```

*My question*: is it possible for a field to have tow values at a same time in a specific record? of course no.

If you have a `range` of values for `CTRL_NUMBER` and you want to update your table on base of them you can do your update with following where clauses:

```
WHERE CTRL_NUMBER BETWEEN range1 AND range2
```

or

```
 WHERE CTRL_NUMBER >= range1 AND CTRL_NUMBER <= range2
```

*But:* if you have not an specific range and you have different values for `CTRL_NUMBER` then you can use `IN` operator with your where clause:

```
WHERE CTRL_NUMBER IN (value1,value2,value3,etc)
```

You can also have your values from another `select` statement:

```
WHERE CTRL_NUMBER IN (SELECT value FROM anotherTable)
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the IN clause -

```
UPDATE STOCK SET PCC_AUTO_KEY=36 WHERE CTRL_NUMBER IN (54252, 58334)
```

Your statement is trying to update where CTRL_NUMBER is 54252 AND 58334, but it can only be one of those at a time.
If you changed your statement to

```
UPDATE STOCK SET PCC_AUTO_KEY=36 WHERE CTRL_NUMBER=54252 OR CTRL_NUMBER=58334
```

it would work.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE STOCK SET PCC_AUTO_KEY=36 WHERE CTRL_NUMBER IN (54252, 58334)
```

or

```
UPDATE STOCK SET PCC_AUTO_KEY=36 WHERE (CTRL_NUMBER=54252 OR CTRL_NUMBER=58334)
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the IN clause would probably be the best way, as answered by czuroski, the problem with using the AND clause in your statement is that the record would have to have both ctrl_numbers in one record, so 0 records would return and no update would be done (and no error) ... In addition to the IN statement you could use an OR clause and it would be:

... WHERE (CTRL_NUMBER = 54252 OR CTRL_NUMBER = 58334)

Using the ( ) allows you to have other WHERE criteria, but I, too, typically use the IN for multiple requirements in the same field.